# According to the statement, was the result positive always?

Tags: applications

The expression:

$\dfrac{r}{pq}$, with $r$, $p$ and $q$ integers and ($p$ and $q$) $\neq 0$,

is positive if:

$$\frac{r}{p} > 0 \text{ and } q > 0 \tag 1$$

True, $\frac{r}{p} \cdot \frac{1}{q}$ because $\text{positive} \times \text{positive}$ is always positive

$$pq < 0 \text{ and } r \tag 2$$ **not** positive

True, because $\frac{r}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{pq}$ and $\text{negative} \times \text{negative}$ is always positive.

My problem is that the correct answer is only I, so what am I failing to think that the second is correct?

Comment: For case $(2)$, it's negative${\,\times\,}$positive, since $\frac{r}{1}$ is negative, and $\frac{1}{pq}$ is positive.

Comment: Why ? pq < 0 , then negative too

Comment: But your post has $pq > 0$.

Comment: My error, edited

Comment: With the edit, you are right, of course.